# Diferença entre "virar" e "tornar-se"

Tags: uso-de-palavras, diferenças

Os dicionários se referem aos verbos *virar* e *tornar-se* como sinônimos, sem muita explicação.

Existe alguma diferença, mesmo que não seja estritamente de significado, entre os dois? Pode-se sempre substituir um pelo outro? É um mais formal do que o outro?

Comment: Eu acredito que tornar-se é mais formal. Acredito que há casos que podemos usar um e não podemos usar outro. Exemplo:
Ele *tornou-se* mais respeitável.
Não sei se podemos usar o verbo virar nesse caso.

Comment: Uma diferença bem evidente é que *virar* tem outra acepção, na qual não é sinônimo de *tornar-se*: *a calça virou do avesso*, *o sonoplasta virou o disco*, *você precisa virar a massa para ficar tostada por igual dos dois lados*.

Comment: @Peixoto Encontro exemplos do género [neste corpus](http://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/corpus.php?corpus=CBRAS): _Todo-poderoso da empresa, ele virou mais poderoso ainda_

Comment: se quiser passar uma ideia de evolução tornou-se se encaixa melhor; para indicar uma simples troca de status ou identidade cabe usar virar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

São essencialmente a mesma coisa quando usados como verbos copulativos. *Virar* é mais usado no Brasil. Em Portugal, quando é usado, é-o em contextos mais informais, enquanto *tornar-se* pode ser usado em todos os registos.

Em termos de significado, *virar* parece-me transmitir uma ideia de transformação mais abrupta (com menos duração) do que *tornar-se*. Em Portugal, tende também a ser usado em frases mais curtas, sem determinante no predicado (*a lagarta virou borboleta*).

Podemos encontrar vários exemplos de *virar* em texto jornalístico português (citações do CETEMPúblico):

> A primeira impressão é que Bobby McFerrin *virou baterista*.
>   Évora *virou «laranja»*, com os sociais-democratas a tornarem-se nos mais votados neste círculo alentejano.
>   Mais um velho caso em que o provisório *virou definitivo*, ou seja, a escola consiste em pavilhões pré-fabricados postos na Amora para servirem durante um ano, mas que resistem há nove.
>   A expressão «cair na real» *virou uma expressão «clássica» no Brasil* para dizer algo assim

Como podes ver, além de sintagmas nominais, temos adjetivos seguindo-se ao verbo, o que é normal nos verbos copulativos.

Answer (score 0):

No dia a dia `virar` e `tornar` são usados indistintamente sem problemas, porém, em alguns casos veja como soa estranho a substituição:

`O carro virou a esquina` - Sentença no sentido figurado que conseguimos entender perfeitamente

`O carro tornou a esquina` - Repare que, mesmo que os dicionários os coloquem como sinônimos, a frase soa estranha. Problema esse de substituição que não existe no caminho inverso: tornar sendo substituído por virar.

Assim, creio que há uma sútil diferença que faz com que nem toda situação onde se possa usar `virar` pode ser substituída por `tornar`, porém, toda situação onde cabe `tornar` pode receber o `virar`.

Comment: A pergunta é sobre os casos em que as palavras tem o mesmo significado. Pelo menos em pt-br usamos somente O carro virou na/a esquina; Sua segunda frase seria facilmente confundida com O carro retornou na esquina; e o uso comum também seria O carro fez o retorno na esquina.

Comment: @AndréLyra Sim, fica estranho. Por isso eu disse que nem toda situação onde se possa usar `virar `pode ser substituída por `tornar`

Answer (score -4):

É simples.

Virar significa "turns" em inglês
Tornar-se significa "becomes" em inglês

Comment: Não é totalmente verdade. Eu posso dizer em português: Eu virei um bandido. Tradução para inglês: I becames a bad guy.

Comment: Sugiro melhorar a resposta. Adicionar mais informações e referências.